# Tabs RenderFlex overflowed by 20 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, tabs

I'm new in flutter and I'm trying to resolve this issue.

**Updated My Code**

After setting `width` and `height` of `container`, I'm getting this output now

[image]
Desirable output

[image]

**TabsContainer.dart**

```
 class TabsContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image, tittle;

  const TabsContainer({Key? key, required this.image, required this.tittle})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: 46,
            width: 46,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Text(
          tittle,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**categorypage.dart**

```
 List<Tab> tabs = [
const Tab(
    height: 50,
      child: TabsContainer(
          image: 'assets/images/g.png', tittle: 'Social Media'),
    ),
 const Tab(


height: 50,
    child: TabsContainer(
        image: 'assets/images/g.png', tittle: 'Interior Design')),
];

    List<Widget> tabsContent = [
    const SocialMedia(),
  
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: tabs.length,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded,
                    size: 30, color: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor),
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications,
                      size: 30, color: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor),
                )
              ],
              elevation: 0.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
          backgroundColor: AppColors.fBackgroundColor,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      'Category',
                      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "ROCK"),
                    )),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                TabBar(
                    automaticIndicatorColorAdjustment: false,
                    indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                    isScrollable: true,
                    tabs: tabs),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      children: tabsContent),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try with `Tab(height:x)`

Comment: I tried but nothing happens. This only works when I change the `width` and `height` of `TabsContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
class TabsContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image, tittle;

  const TabsContainer({Key? key, required this.image, required this.tittle})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 70,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Image.asset(image),
        ),
        Text(
          tittle,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: by reducing height it solve but container width damaged.

Comment: Please share image what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Tab: the default height is 72.0 pixels. Without an `icon`, the height is 46.0 pixels.

We need to provide our custom height in this case. And for decoration, use `ClipRRect` for on image.

```dart
class TabsContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image, tittle;

  const TabsContainer({Key? key, required this.image, required this.tittle})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            // as for  Desirable output, both height and width will be same
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ), // you can use padding here
        Text(
          tittle,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And `tabs` will be like

```dart
 List<Tab> tabs = [
    const Tab(
      height: 50 +
          10 +
          24, // image height + padding/space + 24 for font, better will be getting text size from theme
      child: TabsContainer(
          image:  ...
    ),
```

I will also encourage you to check `icon` and `text` property for this case. The image size is ok up to 46, if you increase the size, you need to provide `Tab(height:)` to fix the overflow. You can use `unselectedLabelStyle` and `labelStyle` for text on `TabBar`.

In this case `tabs` will be

```dart
List<Tab> tabs = [
    Tab(
      text: 'Social Media',
      icon: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/image01.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          // as for  Desirable output, both height and width will be same
          height: 46,
          width: 46,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Tab(
      text: 'Interior Design',
      icon: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/image02.png',
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
          // as for  Desirable output, both height and width will be same
          height: 46,
          width: 46,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ];
```

Comment: kindly see the image above I've updated it now looks like that after putting your same code

Comment: Are you providing height ?  you can try with `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: I've tried it but nothing happens. Check it now I've updated my code